# CRUD how to set SetModel on Master/Detail

Tags: crud, master-detail, atk4

This is not a question, but a "detail" that I don't know how many of you know. Anyway I want to make it public due it take me a while to understand what problem it causes.

I'm in the middle of a CRUD (Master/Detail) case.
Originally I wrote:

```
   $tab = $tabs->addTab('Servizi');
    $qrud = $tab->add('CRUD')->setModel('service');
    if ($qrud->grid) {
         $qrud->grid->addColumn('expander','services','Actions');
```

But it doesn't show me the "expander" button, I controlled the model, the source code many times, etc. At the end I tryed to follow the examples LITERALLY, and change the line with SetModel to another line like:

```
   $tab = $tabs->addTab('Servizi');
    $qrud = $tab->add('CRUD');
    $qrud->setModel('service');
    if ($qrud->grid) {
         $qrud->grid->addColumn('expander','services','Actions');
```

AND VOILA!!!!! it worked like a charm.

I know that this is very simple thing, but for people like me, starting with ATK4, I hope, this should be helpful.

Regards,

Mack

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's a simple case, but sometimes we make mistakes.

That's because `add('CRUD')` returns CRUD object, but `setModel('Foo')` returns Model object.

So, if you make your chain like this: `$c = $this->add('CRUD')->setModel('Foo')`, then `$c` will be Model object not CRUD object !